# Finding the max of a R dataframe column ignoring -Inf and NA

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a R dataFrame from which some columns have -Inf and Na. I would like to find the max of a specific column ignoring the Inf and NA. My dataFrame df is as follow:

```
column1     column2
  -Inf        2
   4          8
   Na         5
   7          4
   10         4
```

I tried using

```
temp=df
temp[is.infinite(temp)]<-NA
my_max=max(temp$column1, na.rm=TRUE)
```

but I get the following error:

```
Error in is.infinite(temp) : default method not implemented for type 'list'
```

I would like to my_max to be equal to 10. How can I tackle this problem?

Comment: `temp[is.infinite(temp)]<-NA` is your problem - `is.infinite` only works on vectors, not whole `data.frame`s at once. Your logic is fine though - `max(replace(data$column1, is.infinite(data$column1), NA), na.rm=TRUE)` will work for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be the following:

```
data <- data.frame(column1 = c(-Inf, 4, NA, 7, 10), column2 = c(2, 8, 5, 4, 4))
column1b <- data$column1[which(!is.na(data$column1))]
column1c <- column1b[which(column1b < Inf)]
max(column1c)
```

Comment: thank you but why the column1b <= 10; because I do know what is the maximum from a bigger dataset.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, I fixed it to Inf.

Comment: Thank you Joachim, your example works fine, but when I try that method on my dataset, I get -Inf as my_max. I am not sure what the problem is

Comment: it works now. I change data$column1 to data[,column1] and it works. thanks a lot

Answer (score 19):

The function `is.finite` will identify elements in a (numeric) vector that are **not** in

- `NA`
- `NaN`
- `Inf`
- `-Inf`

Thus, this function can subset your column of interest in one step.

```
temp <- read.table(text = "
  column1     column2
  -Inf        2
   4          8
   NA         5
   7          4
   10         4",
   header = TRUE)

max(temp$column1[is.finite(temp$column1)])
# [1] 10
```

Answer (score 5):

There is a simple solution in the hablar package. BY adding s() before max you avoid this problem.

```
data <- data.frame(column1 = c(-Inf, 4, NA, 7, 10), column2 = c(2, 8, 5, 4, 4))

max(s(data$column1))
```

Return 10 and have ignores the Inf and NA of the vector.

Answer (score 0):

A method I used when reading from a .csv file that contained blank fields:

```
df[df==""] <- NA
df <- na.omit(df)
print(max(df[,1]))
```